# Web safe small caps font for both mac and windows

Tags: css, fonts, smallcaps, web-safe-fonts

I am trying to find a web safe small caps font for both Windows and Mac for a project I am working on.  I have tried using Copperplate as suggested here http://www.cssfontstack.com/, but have found that on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 the support is spotty at best.  Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: why do you want a web safe font?Any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, I am using an interface that only can access system fonts and needs to be compatible with Windows and Mac by default.

Comment: oK, So is it like this you cant use online fonts...

Comment: Correct, no online fonts -- only fonts that are compatible on both operating systems.